# Метод gzcompress из PHP в C#

Tags: php, c#

Каким методом в C# можно заменить метод сжатия строки из PHP

```
gzcompress("string", число степени сжатия)
```

Comment: [GZipStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) Вам в помощь.

Comment: Судя по этому [вопросу-ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4080344/5796587) GZipStream не является прямым аналогом, т.к. результат будет содержать дополнительные header и footer. Можно попробовать DeflateStream. Но для точного ответа хотелось бы образец входных и выходных байт полученных функцией из PHP. Настраивать у себя весь этот зоопарк как-то нет желания.

Comment: @rdorn `gzcompress("test message in php", 9);` `xЪ+I-.QИM-.NLOUИМS(И(  I%`

Comment: @Александр бинарные данные лучше в hex или base64 показывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полного аналога нет.

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать `DelateStream` или `GZipStream`. Но надо учитывать, что полученные массивы байт будут отличаться:

```
|gzcompress|DeflateStream|GZipStream|gzencode|
|PHP       |.net 4+      |.net 4+   |PHP     |
|----------|-------------|----------|--------|---
|          |             |31        |31      |
|          |             |139       |139     |
|          |             |8         |8       | h
|          |             |0         |0       | e
|          |             |0         |0       | a
|          |             |0         |0       | d
|          |             |0         |0       | e
|          |             |0         |0       | r
|120       |             |4         |2       |
|218       |             |0         |3       |
|----------|-------------|----------|--------|---
|43        |43           |43        |43      |
|73        |73           |73        |73      | c
|45        |45           |45        |45      | o
|46        |46           |46        |46      | m
|81        |81           |81        |81      | p
|200       |200          |200       |200     | r
|77        |77           |77        |77      | e
|45        |45           |45        |45      | s
|46        |46           |46        |46      | s
|78        |78           |78        |78      | e
|76        |76           |76        |76      | d
|79        |79           |79        |79      |
|85        |85           |85        |85      | c
|200       |200          |200       |200     | o
|204       |204          |204       |204     | n
|83        |83           |83        |83      | t
|40        |40           |40        |40      | e
|200       |200          |200       |200     | n
|40        |40           |40        |40      | t
|0         |0            |0         |0       |
|0         |0            |0         |0       |
|----------|-------------|----------|--------|---
|73        |             |17        |17      |
|21        |             |189       |189     | f
|7         |             |70        |70      | o
|37        |             |177       |177     | o
|          |             |19        |19      | t
|          |             |0         |0       | e
|          |             |0         |0       | r
|          |             |0         |0       |
```

Во всех четырех случаях использовалось максимально доступное в настройках сжатие текста `"test message in php"`.

Как не сложно заметить, сжатый контент совпадает, а дополнительные header и footer  отличаются.

> Тут надо сделать серьезную оговорку, что совпадение контента обусловлено его длиной и содержимым и, в общем случае, на это рассчитывать не стоит (см. ниже), но полученный набор байт, в любом случае, может быть распакован при соответствующей корректировке заголовков.

Также при сравнении стоит учесть, что в версиях .net меньше 4 была использована собственная реализация алгоритмов Deflate, мягко говоря, неудачная. Начиная с 4.0 используется zlib.

Кроме того, оригинальная PHP-функция позволяет выбирать из десяти возможных степеней сжатия (0 - без сжатия, 9 - максимальное). DeflateStream и GZipStream позволяют выбирать только из трех вариантов: `None`, `Fastest`, `Optimal`, при этом не очевидно как между собой соотносятся оригинальные уровни zlib и предложенные уровни потоков (ну кроме None).

Ну и всегда остается возможность самостоятельно реализовать необходимые функции, импортировав их из zlib. Можно подсмотреть как это сделано в исходниках DeflateStream или GzipStream.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public static class PhpCompress
{
    public static byte[] GzUncompress(byte[] data)
    {
        using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using var zipStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        using var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
        compressedStream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        return resultStream.ToArray();
    }

    public static byte[] GzCompress(byte[] data, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        GzCompress(data, stream, compressionLevel);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public static void GzCompress(byte[] data, Stream targetStream, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)
    {
        Span<byte> header = stackalloc byte[2];
        header[0] = 0x78;
        header[1] = 0x9c;
        targetStream.Write(header);

        using var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using (var zipStream = new DeflateStream(targetStream, compressionLevel, true))
        {
            sourceStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
            // zipStream.Flush() is superfluous
        }

        var adlerCrc = Adler32(data);
        Span<byte> crcBuffer = stackalloc byte[4];
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32BigEndian(crcBuffer, adlerCrc);
        targetStream.Write(crcBuffer);
    }

    private static uint Adler32(byte[] str)
    {
        const int mod = 65521;
        uint a = 1, b = 0;
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            a = (a + c) % mod;
            b = (b + a) % mod;
        }

        return (b << 16) | a;
    }
}
```